# Why does Azure file/blob storage use table requests

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have an Azure storage account that uses blob and file storage but we seem to be incurring table requests and a few queue requests even though we haven't  created any tables or queues. I assume they are to support the file storage upload/download in some way but I wanted to understand how and why to determine accurate usage for both monitoring and billing.

[image]

Comment: Are you using WebJobs at all?

Comment: No, there's nothing else in the subscription at all at the moment. Is it to support stats maybe?

Comment: Tables...definitely to store storage analytics data. Not sure about queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gaurav Mantri mentioned, Tables are used to store Azure Storage Analytics metrics. You can find there are multi tables whose name is start with $Metrics.

[image]

The amount of storage used by metrics data is also billable. The following actions performed by Storage Analytics are also billable:

1. Requests to create blobs for logging.
2. Requests to create table entities for metrics.

You can enable or disable the metrics on Azure portal.

[image]

To find why your queue was used, I suggest you enable Queue logs on Diagnostics tab of Azure portal. You will find the detail usage of your queue in following blob.

```
<servicetype>/YYYY/MM/DD/HHMM/<counter>.log
```

Comment: That's really useful info thanks. I'll have a dig about in the portal to find the tables you mention. Thanks again.